# One signup form - different subscription list?

Tags: forms, validation, newsletter, mailchimp

I'm trying to create a newsletter. I've looked at Mailchimp and ubivox.

Is it possible to create a signup form with the options (as checkboxes) for people to choose which list they want to be subscribed to?

Fx, it could be: "I only want you to send mw news about this." "And I want to subscribe to two of the things." "And I want to subscribe to everything!"

And theese different choices would be different lists in my newsletter client.

Can you make one form for several lists? 
Or do you need a form for each list?

Comment: Questions about **general computing hardware and software** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](http://superuser.com/about).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm more familiar with Campaign Monitor, but the general concept is the same; you should use one master list then separate each of your lists (sub-lists) into segments.

You can then easily have a custom field (checkboxes) to control which segment (list) they are subscribed to, and also have a master subscribe option available.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. The caveat being you'll need to use the [MailChimp API](http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/) to create a custom sign-up form on your site.

The embeddable forms provided by MailChimp will not be able to do this.